# SignalR Issues with multiple requests

Tags: asp.net, signalr

In my application, I'm hosting a fairly CPU-intensive engine on a web server, which is connected to clients via SignalR. From the client, the server will be signalled to do some work (via an AJAX request), and every 200ms will send down a queue of "animation events" which describe the work being done.

This is the code used to set up the connection on the client:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'serverSentEvents', 'longPolling'] })
```

And here's the related code in the backend:

```
    private const int PUSH_INTERVAL = 200;
    private ManualResetEvent _mrs;

    private void SetupTimer(bool running)
    {
        if (running)
        {
            UpdateTimer = new Timer(PushEventQueue, null, 0, PUSH_INTERVAL);
        }
        else
        {
            /* Lock here to prevent race condition where the final call to PushEventQueue()
             * could be followed by the timer calling PushEventQueue() one last time and
             * thus the End event would not be the final event to arrive clientside,
             * which causes a crash */
            _mrs = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            UpdateTimer.Dispose(_mrs);
            _mrs.WaitOne();
            Observer.End();
            PushEventQueue(null);
        }
    }

    private void PushEventQueue(object state)
    {
        SentMessages++;
        SignalRConnectionManager<SimulationHub>.PushEventQueueToClient(ConnectionId, new AnimationEventSeries { AnimationPackets = SimulationObserver.EventQueue.FlushQueue(), UpdateTime = DateTime.UtcNow });
    }


    public static void PushEventQueueToClient(string connectionId, AnimationEventSeries series)
    {
        HubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).queue(series);
    }
```

And for completeness' sake, the related Javascript method:

```
self.hub.client.queue = function(data) {
    self.eventQueue.addEvents(data);
};
```

When testing this functionality on localhost, it works absolutely smoothly, with no delay (as you would expect), using serverSentEvents as a transport method.

However, when used in production, this more often than not takes a very long time to complete. Using SignalR's logging and a bit of my own instrumentation, it can be seen that the first series of events reaches the client within a couple of seconds, which is totally acceptable. However, after that SignalR often gives the following error:

```
Keep alive has been missed, connection may be dead/slow.
```

Followed soon after by:

```
Keep alive timed out. Notifying transport that connection has been lost.
```

This will happen a few times, and then eventually, up to a minute later, the events will arrive, with my own instrumentation showing that they were sen from the server approximately 200ms apart, as expected. It can also be seen that in production, they were sent with the primary transport method, web sockets.

Is anyone aware of any issues that sending multiple SignalR requests on a timer might cause? Like I say, this primarily seems to happen with web sockets. I've been told that using web sockets is best practice, so I'm keen to keep using them, but if there isn't a workaround to these kinds of issues, then I'm afraid I'll have to remove them permanently.

### Edit

I've now removed the option to use web sockets on the live site, and I'm running into the same issues with server sent events - several failed attempts to reconnect after the first queue update arrives.

Comment: Its often the case that there are problems with proxies etc for SignalR. Do you have the same performance issues if you force the connection to use SSE or LongPolling transports?

Comment: I've actually just been testing that this minute. Basically, I just removed the "webSockets" entry from that array, and I'm looking at the network log in Chrome now. 

It's now constantly trying to reconnect with server sent events, and failing consistently. Again, one packet came through and the rest are blocked. I'll update the question to include this.

Comment: And I assume that longpolling is fine and happy?

Comment: Long polling seems to be more reliable, but again, incredibly slow to an unacceptable standard.

Comment: What is your production environment? - an online shared host, or corporate production environment or...?

Comment: We're currently hosting the website on an Azure instance - it's a corporate production environment, but it's pre-release, so downtime is somewhat acceptable for the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64701/discussion-between-jon-egerton-and-dan-mcelroy).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summing up our discussion, I don't think there are specific issues with websockets/signalr on azure.

I've sample code here: https://github.com/jonegerton/SignalR.StockTicker which can be used for testing, with some minor tweaks (I'll probably develop it as a test platform at some point).

Its based on the sample project from MS which can be found here: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR-StockTicker.

I've put an example in azure here (http://stockticker.azurewebsites.net) for testing purposes. It has the default transport configurations enabled (ie websockets >> serversentevents >> longpolling)

Comment: Can you help me for this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765288/lazy-loading-with-signalr